# Non-unique elements for custom datatypes

Tags: c#

I am trying to get list of unique elements for a custom datatype. I seriously couldn't figure out why this doesn't work. The control never reaches the Equals implementation in the below code. Could someone please help with this?

```
public class customobj : IEqualityComparer<customobj>
{
    public string str1;
    public string str2;

    public customobj(string s1, string s2)
    {
        this.str1 = s1; this.str2 = s2;
    }

    public bool Equals(customobj obj1, customobj obj2)
    {
        if ((obj1 == null) || (obj2 == null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return ((obj1.str1.Equals(obj2.str1)) && (obj2.str2.Equals(obj2.str2)));

    }

    public int GetHashCode(customobj w)
    {
        if (w != null)
        {
            return ((w.str1.GetHashCode()) ^ (w.str2.GetHashCode()));
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And below is the part where i am trying to retrieve distinct elements of list.

```
List<customobj> templist = new List<customobj> { };

templist.Add(new customobj("10", "50"));
templist.Add(new customobj("10", "50"));
List<customobj> dist = templist.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class does not override base Equals() from object class, and `Distinct()` is using it.

Try overriding base Equals, and calling your custom  `Equals(Rectangle obj1, Rectangle obj2)` from there.

Also, if you want to inherit from typed comparer, use `IEquatable<T>` , but not `IEqualityComparer<Rectangle>`

Answer (score 1):

```
bool Equals(Rectangle obj1, Rectangle obj2)
```

is a static method of Object, so it can't be overridden.

You must override the instance Equals instead.

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement IEqualityComparer in Rectangle's class you should to write something this:

```
List<Rectangle> dist = templist.Distinct(new Reclangle("","")).ToList();
```

Usually it is implements through an RectangleComparer class:

```
class RectangleComparer : IEqualityComparer<Rectangle>
{
   public static IEqualityComparer<Rectangle> Instance { get {...} }
...
}

List<Rectangle> dist = templist.Distinct(RectangleComparer.Instance).ToList();
```

Or override GetHashCode and Equals =)

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing the wrong interface.  Your class implements `IEqualityComparer<Rectangle>`, not `IEquatable<Rectangle>`.  Unless you *pass in* an `IEqualityComparer` to `Distinct`, it will use either `IEquatable.Equals` (if youe class implements it) or `Object.Equals`.

```
public class Rectangle : IEquatable<Rectangle>
{
    public string width;
    public string height;

    public Rectangle(string s1, string s2)
    {
        this.width = s1; this.height = s2;
    }

    `IEquatable.Equals
    public bool Equals(Rectangle obj2)
    {
        if (obj2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return ((this.width.Equals(obj2.width)) && (this.height.Equals(obj2.height)));

    }

    `override of object.Equals
    public override bool Equals(Object(o2)
    {
       if(typeof(o2) == typeof(Rectangle))
           return ((Rectangle)this.Equals((Rectangle)o2);

       return false;
    } 

    'override of object.GetHashCode
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return ((this.width.GetHashCode()) ^ (thisw.height.GetHashCode()));
    }
}
```

Also, is there a particular reason why your `width` and `height` are `string`s and not numeric types?  It seems very odd, and could lead to weird bugs such as assuming that `"100"` and `"0100"` and `" 100 "` are equal, when in fact they are distinct strings and will have different hash codes.

Comment: Thanks.. this clarified my understanding